# Kernel Error in IJulia notebook--Failed to Start the Kernel in Jupyter

Tags: julia, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, ijulia-notebook

Do you know how to fix this kernel error and what caused it?
[image]

I have called Julia from xterm bash like the following photo:
[image]

Comment: Please, please do not attach textual data in form of images - This makes it nearly impossible for others with a similar  problem to find your question.

Comment: it is impossible to copy it! I am not sure what is the reason but I understand as well that text is better! There was no way to copy the kernel error!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I used the following commands and then the kernel starts successfully in IJulia Notebook:

```
Pkg.update()
Pkg.build("IJulia")
using IJulia; notebook()
```

Comment: I usually start Jupyter from the terminal: `jupyter notebook`, I feel is more transparent.

Comment: @amrods this doesn't work for me as it shows this error : `ERROR: LoadError: Blosc not installed properly, run Pkg.build("ZMQ"), restart Julia and try again` and this one at the same time : `ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile ZMQ [c2297ded-f4af-51ae-bb23-16f91089e4e1] to /root/.julia/compiled/v1.3/ZMQ/CaaO6_riTu7.ji.`